# Wordfence | Microsoft Azure

Tags: php, wordpress, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm working with Wordpress Multisite on an Azure Server. To maintain the security of the sites I did the installation of Wordfence Security, however, when I check the logs, I see the error:

`PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required 'D:\home\site\wwwroot/wordfence-waf.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in Unknown on line 0`

Looking at the solution, I saw some pages saying that I would have to change something in .htacess, but in azure I do not have .htacess only web.config.

How can I fix this error ?
Which file should I modify and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.htaccess is for Apache.

For Azure, you will need to modify the PHP ini file to use [auto prepend file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) and use the full path to the wordfence-waf.php file.